# Generate Permutations - Swap Function

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

I'm going thru the EPI book and adapting the solutions in Go. I don't understand the solution for "generating permutations". Below is my implementation in Go (which works correctly):

```golang
    func permutations(A []int) [][]int {
    result := [][]int{}
    var directedPermutations func(i int)
    directedPermutations = func(i int) {
        if i == len(A)-1 {
            B := make([]int, len(A))
            copy(B, A)
            result = append(result, B)
            return
        }
        for j := i; j < len(A); j++ {
            A[i], A[j] = A[j], A[i]
            directedPermutations(i + 1)
            A[i], A[j] = A[j], A[i]
        }
    }
    directedPermutations(0)
    return result
}
```

Below is the result:

```sh
16.3_generate_permutations$  go run main.go
input:  [1 2 3]
[[1 2 3] [1 3 2] [2 1 3] [2 3 1] [3 2 1] [3 1 2]]
```

Specifically, I'm confused as to why the values are swapped before and *after* the recursive case. I've stepped thru with a debugger and see that for each successive call values are swapped to generate the permutation.

Is the *swap before recursive case and swap back afterwards* a common pattern?

Comment: Not sure exactly *how* common, but yes, generally speaking it's quite normal to do some setup before calling a function (whether or not it's recursive) and then undo it afterwards; e.g. open a file first and close it afterwards, hold a lock and release it afterwards, etc. For algorithms in particular, the Dancing Links algorithm is another recursive example; a node from a linked list is removed before the recursive call, and reinserted afterwards.